# Can't pass a xml from as3 to php

Tags: php, xml, actionscript-3, flash

So I have these two scripts that comunicate with each other to create a xml file online. The way I have it now, AS3 swf sends a few variables to a php script to write. I got the creating part, but for some reason, the php does not write a xml file. I tried changing the variable to a simple "foobar" string, and it works. But If I do a:

```
var temp:XML = new XML(<test></test>);
```

It doesen't write it. So what's up, is this normal?

AS3

```
function SaveXml(inputxml:XML){
    var temp:XML = <teste></teste>;
    var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    variables.xmlfile = temp;
    variables.folder = TestProperties.Username;
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("savexml.php");
    request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    request.data = variables;

    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;

    try{
        loader.load(request);
    }
    catch (error:Error) {
        trace("Unable to load URL");
    }

    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

    function completeHandler(e:Event)
    {
                //something when complete;
    }
    }
```

PHP

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('GMT');

$xmlfile = $_POST["xmlfile"];
$folder = $_POST["folder"];
$filename = date('ymdhis').".xml";

if(! file_exists("./user/".$folder."/")){
    mkdir("./user/".$folder."/", 0777);
}

$handle = fopen("user/".$folder."/".$filename, 'w+');
fwrite($handle, $xmlfile );
fclose($handle);

echo "result=success";
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried google?

http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=169554

Comment: While I appreciate the help, I could live withouth the irony. And yes, I tried googling, most problems I found were loader and crossdomain issues, which isn't the case here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create a xml in flash like you did.

```
var temp:XML = <teste></teste>;
```

Because there is no object like  in your file. What you need to do is provide a string as a parameter when instantiating the XML object.

So, you should do something like below,

```
var temp:XML = new XML("<teste></teste>");
```

Now your code can send xml to php.

Comment: Thank you. I (mistakenly) thought XML didnt need to be called as string. Maybe XMLList? Anyway, it's working, thanks.